# Regional Spellings

Tags: discussion

Ok, so aerovistae and Larry edited my answer to [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/what-is-the-difference-between-an-intake-manifold-and-a-fuel-rail), with the only change being to change 'carburettor' to 'carburetor'. Now, my immediate response was to roll back the edit, because as far as I'm concerned, my original is the correct spelling - but I'm well aware that the second version is the U.S. spelling (and, indeed, both with -er are considered correct in other regions)

When I've been editing posts, I've always left regional spellings - tyres vs tires being a common one - in the original poster's dialect, which I thought was the general principle on this site? After all, we have a pretty global userbase...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roll back is fine. I was unaware of that being a correct spelling.

Answer (score 5):

That sounds like a reasonable roll back: I certainly didn't realize that there was a regional spelling for that part.  It's not impossible that they were also unaware.

Answer (score 2):

What Bob and Larry said. Most people who make these types of edits simply mistakenly think the person was just a bad speller.

I am a ruthless grammar nazi on some sites, and someone corrected me once when I fixed something that was actually considered correctly spelled in his country. I can't remember if we rolled it back or not, but if I know the spelling can differ from country to country, I'll leave it in the format used by the poster.